# Why this program is returning 10 as the value of j after assigning it to k ? where as k=12

Tags: c

The value of j and k in output is 10 and 10. But in this program I've assigned k=12.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int j=10,k=12;
    if(k>=j)
    {
        {
            k=j;
            j=k;
            printf("%d\n%d",j,k);
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `k = j;` changes the value of `k` .  It is no longer 12 after that

Comment: What do you suppose the `k=j` line does? What does that imply for `j=k` after that? Did you try using the debugger?

Comment: You set `k = j` when j is 10, so k is set to 10. Then you set `j = k` when k is 10, so j is set to 10. Then you print both, and both are equal to 10. What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: Are you trying to swap k and j? (so k is 10 and j is 12 when you print?)

Answer (score 3):

Erroneous code:

```
// k = 12, j = 10
k = j; // k => 10
j = k; // j => 10
```

Use the operation below if you want to swap the values of k and j:

```
// k = 12, j = 10
k = k + j; // k => 22
j = k - j; // j => 22 - 10 => 12
k = k - j; // k => 22 - 12 => 10
```

Comment: nice, never thought about in-place value swapping

Answer (score 1):

```
int j=10,k=12;
if(k>=j) // k is superior or equal to j, so true
{
    {
        k=j;  // now k=10
        j=k;  // now j=10
        printf("%d\n%d",j,k); //so you'll print 10 and 10
    }
}
```

You first assign the value of `j`, ie 10, to `k`, so after that `k=10`.
Then you assign the value of `k`, which is now `10`, to `j`, so j remains unchanged, and in the end, both have the value `10`.